# Nvidia control panel not detecting multiple displays (and other related issues)

Tags: windows-10, audio, multiple-monitors, hp-pavilion

I recently purchased an [HP Gaming Pavilion](https://support.hp.com/bg-en/document/c06171851) laptop with a GTX 1050 Ti and B&O audio.

Today I plugged in a TV via the laptop’s HDMI port, but when I did so the Nvidia Control Panel stopped showing the built-in display. It still appears in the Windows Settings app, but I was hoping to configure it further with the nCP.

[laptop display shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKxo9.png)
[laptop display missing when tv connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuErE.png)

Additionally, the built-in speakers changed name from B&O audio to Realtek High Definition, and some software now thinks the laptop speakers are actually headphones.
[speaker name changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLnkh.png)

Even if I unplug the TV the speakers’ name remains changed, and I don’t know whether the B&O software is working properly.